# How can I use a Bluetooth headset in an ATR 72 cockpit?

Tags: aircraft-systems, atr-72

Is there any device available to connect a pair of Bluetooth earphones to the audio system of an [ATR 72 aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATR_72), to receive and transmit on the radio?

The stock headsets are horrible. I own a David Clarke headset too but the cables are a little annoying. If there's a solution to use a Bluetooth headset with a mike to replace the headset in the aircraft it would be lovely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flying Magazine [reviewed headsets for pilots](http://www.flyingmag.com/avionics-gear/pilot-supplies/pilot-headsets-review-top-models) back in 2013 and four years ago there were already bluetooth-capable headsets in the market from Bose, David Clark, Sennheiser and Lightspeed. You might want to start there...